# How do i create symlink in mingw64?

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I am writing a C program in which i want to create symlinks but i could not find function which could help me. Is it possible to create symlinks in c using mingw?
If yes, how can we do it?

Comment: There are 139 questions that a search of "create symlink on windows" turns up here. Please read those before asking yet another one and delete this one!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt those question are on creating symlinks on windows. I want to create symlinks in c using mingw. You wont find a single question on that(I dont want answers in msys). Please read the question carefully before commenting

Comment: `man 2 symlink` good luck :)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin I didn't get that. What does 'man 2 symlink' mean?

Comment: You are on Windows, @Vishal, so each of these other question applies. Given, not every one of them is also using C, but the Windows API is pretty much the same in every programming language.

Comment: @Vishal `symlink` is the posix-defined function for creating symbolic links in the file system. `man` is the program to read manual pages. `man 2 symlink` opens the manual page on symlink in section 2 of the manual pages (system call definitions)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin thank you for the explanation. Can you please tell me how can i use this to create symlinks in windows using mingw and C? Sorry but i am still new to programming

Comment: You can't: See the last sentence in the description of the "mingw" tag when you hover above it with the mouse.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichEckhardt for the clarification. I did search for other similar questions but could not find a solution. Could you please provide a solution?